# Is there such a thing as a manager design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Is there such a thing as a manager design pattern that controls how different entities interact?

This is for a project for which the Environment, `EnvironmentListener`, and Entity classes have been predefined by our professor.

The static class, `Environment`, has a single `EnvironmentListener` interface that has a `nextAction()` method it just continuously calls kind of like a main loop in a game and because it is for a design patterns class, i can't simply change the code.

I need to allow entities to be dragged, dropped, animated, etc. and thought i would do that using different controllers.

I've been wondering if it was a good idea to make a controller manager which would implement `EnvironmentListener` and if a pattern like that existed.

The controller manager would simply iterate through a list of controllers and use their call function.

Comment: In the future, please break down your question into paragraphs - it makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Sounds like you're after the [mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) pattern - which can be thought of as a 'manager' of the objects that it deals with.

Answer (score 18):

In many systems, a manager is also a facade for a sub-system, and in that scenario it is more of a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) design pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Data Manager is the implementation of **Facade** design pastern.
It encapsulate the Connection to the database and the transaction scope.
It holds all the DAOs or Records (lazy or not lazy) of all the tables it responsible and when he creates one it connects it to the connection and transaction.
It can be use as a **singleton** so you work with one data manager.
Data Manager can use cache manager to cache the data that it retrieve from the database and if the same request is issue then it can return the result from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked in 2010, but since at least 2021 ([web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210315000000*/https://www.eventhelix.com/design-patterns/manager/)) there is the page https://www.eventhelix.com/design-patterns/manager/
(Manager Design Pattern). I do not want to discuss here whether or not this *Manager* is a special case of the *Mediator* design pattern.