# Manager class design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

What is a **Manager** class?
What is the difference between Manager class and Object Manager?
Is there any design pattern for it?
Thanks!

Comment: Need more details or rather the context. Where did you hear of this Manager class?

Comment: may be what you are talking about is this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern, and by the way there is no problem described in the question.

Comment: The 'Manager' name for a class sounds to me like a kick to the SRP.

Comment: do you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641505/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-manager-design-pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there such a thing as a manager design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641505/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-manager-design-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Atomic Object [refer](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2008/01/30/presenter-first-get-your-triads-talking/) to the concept of a 'manager' within the context of the Presenter-first MVP variant. Could this be what you're looking for? It acts to co-ordinate MVP triads.