# private static list which contains all object constructed

Tags: java, list, oop, design-patterns, static

I'm writing animation program, in which many balls are running around and bouncing.

I made `Ball` class which represents ball's behaviour.

When I implement ball's collisioin with another ball,
I have to check the all other balls.
So I made this class.

```
public class Ball{

    private static final List<Ball> allBalls;
    static{
        allBalls = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private Ball(){}

    public static Ball getNewBall(){
        Ball ball = new Ball();
        allBalls.add(ball);
        return ball;
    }

    public void collision(){
        for(Ball b : allBalls){
            //check whether b is colliding with me
            //and if colliding, change speed of me and b.
        }
    }

}
```

Is this kind of design (to hold all objects in private static list) good or bad ?

Comment: `getNewBall` is called a **factory method** and must be static. But it is a fine design. As answered already, a separate **factory class** has the advantage of no statics, just one factory instance.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you. Could you explain more detailed the disadvantage of my "private static List and private Constructor" design ?

Comment: Say you have a red room with balls and a blue room with balls. Then you are out of luck. The same holds for a unit test. And of course it is a global variable, that is immediately initialized when you use the class. In contrast a BallFactory (or BallManager, BallRoom, or Balls) can be created once by intend, static or not, and hence is more free.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you. If I want to force all balls be inside the `List`, I make `Ball`'s constructor `protected` and make `BallManager` in same package, and make factory method, right?

Comment: The Ball's constructor without private/protected/public = "package private." But indeed that is the idea.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you. I'll write `BallManager`.

Answer (score 6):

What you should have is a `BallManager` class that will handle that stuff.

```
public class BallManager {
    private static BallManager instance = new BallManager();
    private BallManager(){}
    public static BallManager getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    public List<Ball> ballsInPlay = new ArrayList<>();
    public void createBall(int x, int y) {}
    public void checkCollisions() {
        // loop ball list and check collisions
        // perform cleanup based on collisions
    }
    private void ballCleanup(){}
}

public class Ball{
    public Ball(){}
    public void collision(Ball other){}
}
```

NOTE: Changed from static class to singleton. Also, fixed the compilation error by adding () after checkCollisions method

Comment: Note that you probably don't need all the "static" in the manager

Comment: BallManager can be a singleton. Is there a name for this design pattern though?

Comment: Yeah, singleton is probably best.

Comment: @JavaHopper http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641505/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-manager-design-pattern suggests it sounds like a mediator pattern.

Comment: @JavaHopper you can also look at entity systems for the use of these kind of manager objects. I just haven't really seen what the pattern is actually called.

Comment: I think , ball's behavior (check collisions) should be inside the `Ball` class, so I adopt my design(private static List and private constructor design). Is this true ?

Comment: No, BallManager is meant for the purpose of managing Ball life cycle

Comment: @ShuS JavaHopper is correct. Ball should only check a collision that it has been asked to. It should not know or manage the life cycle of other balls.

Comment: Thank you. I understand.

Comment: also, I recommend to have a boolean property isCollidable to store the state

Answer (score 0):

Create Singleton BallManager using enum.

enum singleton are best to use.

Improving the previous answer.

```
public enum BallManager {
        INSTANCE;
        public List<Ball> ballsInPlay = new ArrayList<>();
        public void createBall(int x, int y) {}
        public void checkCollisions() {
            // loop ball list and check collisions
            // perform cleanup based on collisions
        }
        private void ballCleanup(){}
 }

 public class Ball{
    public Ball(){}
    public void collision(Ball other){}
}
```